# Pole expansion with complex roots

Tags: equation-solving, complex

I have the following function of ω

```
f[ω_] := (
2 Sqrt[Γ] (4*
 g2^2 + (κ1 - 2*I*ω) (κ2 - 2*I*ω)))/(
4*g2^2 (Γ - 
 2*I*ω) + (4*
  g1^2 + (Γ - 2*I*ω) (κ1 - 
    2*I*ω)) (κ2 - 2*I*ω))
```

And I intend to find the roots of the denominator. I do the following:

```
wroots1 = x /. Solve[(Denominator[f[ω]] /. {ω -> x}) == 0, x] // FullSimplify
```

And I get a really long, ugly solution. However, the problem lies with my attempt to obtain the conjugate of wroots1:

```
wroots2 = FullSimplify[Conjugate[wroots1], Assumptions -> {Γ ∈ 
 Reals, κ1 ∈ Reals, κ2 ∈ Reals, 
g1 ∈ Reals, g2 ∈ Reals, 
4 (-16 (Γ + κ1 + κ2)^2 + 
     48 (4 g1^2 + 
        4 g2^2 + Γ κ1 + (Γ + \
κ1) κ2))^3 + 
  4096 (-36 g1^2 (Γ + κ1 - 
        2 κ2) + (2 Γ - κ1 - \
κ2) (36 g2^2 + (Γ + κ1 - 
           2 κ2) (Γ - 
           2 κ1 + κ2)))^2 > 0}]
```

Rather than getting the conjugate of the 3 roots from wroots1, I obtain the same solutions for wroots1 with the exception of the word "conjugate" being tacked in front of certain terms. What is the issue here? I could use any help I can get.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: It doesn't work because expressions depend not only on parameters being reals, but also on their values. You cannot conjugate square root without knowing if expression inside positive or negative.

Comment: @VsevolodA. Thanks for your response. If you were to compile and print wroots1, you'd see that the terms in the square root are precisely part of the conditions that I set to be bigger than 0. Namely: 4(-16(\[Gamma]....) > 0. Those are the only terms that are in the square root of wroots1.

Comment: If all roots are bigger than 0 why don't you just /. I -> -I

Comment: @VsevolodA. I'm not saying that all roots are bigger than 0, I don't know that. If I understand what you said earlier correctly, conjugate doesn't work because it doesn't know if the terms inside the square root is positive or negative. I've circumvented that by setting said condition (the quantities in the square root) to be more than 0 (positive) but it still didn't work

Comment: By roots I meant square roots.

Comment: Look at the real and imaginary parts of the denominator, `ReIm[f[x] // Denominator]`.  The real part is quadratic in $\omega$, or $x$, easily solvable.  That gives the only positive value of $\omega$ that makes the denominator zero.  But, the imaginary part must also be zero, so we have a condition on the parameters.  We can then solve for the value of $\Gamma$, say, that makes the denominator zero at our calculated value of $\omega$.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your previous statement? Do you mean let the complex identity I go to -1? But I is not -1. I do not follow you. I'm sorry.

Comment: @LouisB I'm sorry I don't think I follow as well. \[Omega] is not quadratic if you look at it, it's cubic. Also I'm not solving for \[Gamma] and I don't see how solving for \[Gamma] helps with that. Could you elaborate ?

Comment: I had assumed $\omega \in \text{Reals}$  in my earlier comment.  I don't know where I got that idea.  Sorry for my confusion.  BTW, an earlier comment mentioned `I -> -I` as a way to take the complex conjugate.  If all the parameters are real, including $\omega$, then you can find the complex conjugate of the expression by replacing `I` with `-I`, not with minus one.